# C# method signatures - restricting types - what's the correct terminology?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, delegates, method-signature

I have a method in the `Common` class of a project I am working on which is defined like this:

```
public static void PopulateSoapBody<TEnum>(Object obj, string[] aMessage) where TEnum : struct,  IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
```

and it is called like this (from several different classes defining their own enumerated types, and populating their own soap body classes) :

```
DCSSCardUpdateType wsSoapBody = new DCSSCardUpdateType();
Common.PopulateSoapBody<CardPinRequest>(wsSoapBody, aMessage);
```

where

> *CardPINRequest* is an Enum Type defined in the calling class
>
> *wsSoapBody* is a class type defined in the web service
>
> *aMessage* is a string array (used to populate the *wsSoapBody*)

What is it called when an *enum* type is passed in like that to a method, restricting the possible types (I'd like to read up on it to understand better how to make use of features d like this)

Comment: what do you mean by **these type of generic methods**?

Comment: What is *what* called, exactly? Note that it would really make your code easier to read if you followed normal .NET naming conventions, e.g. `PopulateSoapBody` and `CardPinRequest`.

Comment: This is called a "generic method" with a constrained type parameter.

Comment: You need to start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks, I searched for [dasblinkenlight](http://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) 's suggestion too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *think* the term you are looking for is [generic type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

From the linked MSDN article:

> When you define a generic class, you can apply restrictions to the kinds of types that client code can use for type arguments when it instantiates your class. If client code tries to instantiate your class by using a type that is not allowed by a constraint, the result is a compile-time error. These restrictions are called constraints.